# ddply is Reordering my Data

Tags: r, normalization, plyr

I'm trying to normalize data (subsetted by the variable 'season') using ddply but it is inserting the season variable at the front of the data I'm normalizing (col 4), then shifting all of the data to the right.

I'm new to the dplyr/plyr world so any help is appreciated.

Fully reproducible example:

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(XML)
library(stringr)

# File Names, Functions, Parameters, etc. 
# custom functions
normalize <- function(x) { 
  return((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
}

trim <- function (x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)

first_season <- 2004
last_season <- 2013
num_seasons <- as.numeric(last_season - first_season + 1)

seasons <- seq(first_season, last_season, by=1)
rm(first_season, last_season)

# Passing 
passing <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:num_seasons) {
  url <- paste("http://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/", seasons[i],"/passing.htm", sep = "")
  df <- readHTMLTable(url,which=1)
  df$season = seasons[i]
  df <- df[!names(df) %in% c("QBrec") ] 
  if(df$season >= 2008) df <- df[!names(df) %in% c("QBR") ] # Removes QBR 2008+
  passing <- rbind(passing, df)
  rm(df)
  print(seasons[i])
}

names(passing) <- c("rank_pfr", "nameinfo", "team", "age", "games", "games_started",
                    #"qb_record", 
                    "completions", "attempts", "comp_pct", "yards_passing",
                    "td_passing", "td_pct", "interceptions", "int_pct", "long_passing",
                    "yards_pass_att", "yards_pass_att_avg", "yards_pass_comp", "yards_pass_game", "pass_rate", "sacks", "sacks_pass", "yards_net_pass_att", "yards_net_pass_att_avg", "sacks_pct", "comebacks", "game_win_drives", "season")

passing <- passing[which(passing$rank_pfr!='Rk'), ]

passing[, 4:28] <- apply(passing[,4:28], 2, as.numeric) 

passing[is.na(passing)] <- 0

# Note that season is the last column (both colname and viewing the data)
# colnames(passing)
# View(passing)

passing[, 4:28] <- plyr::ddply(passing[, 4:28], .(season), colwise(normalize))

# Note that season still *appears* to be the last column
# colnames(passing)

# But when you view the data the season values have been
# inserted under age, and everything else seems to be shifted to the right
# View(passing)
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would be easier if you could restrict your minimal working example to only those lines of code where the unexpected reordering happens and provide the input data as `dput`.

Comment: @beginneR Since I'm scrapping the data from multiple sites I don't know of a way to really minimize it.  Plus I've been criticized in the past for not having *enough* code.

Comment: Okay, I understand that. Just thought you would probably get a quicker response. Is it correct that the reordering you describe takes place in the last `ddply` call?

Comment: @beginneR I'm somewhat new to SO so I appreciate the etiquette suggestions too.

Comment: @beginneR The code that reorders it is `passing[, 4:28] <- plyr::ddply(passing[, 4:28], .(season), colwise(normalize))`

Comment: Does this work for you: `passing[, 4:27] <- plyr::ddply(passing[, 4:28], .(season), colwise(normalize))[-1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you describe is a "normal" `plyr` behavior caused by the grouping `.(season)`. As an example, you can do the same with the `mtcars` data set and compare the results.

```
head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Note the position of `carb`.

Using your `normalize` function:

```
ddply(mtcars, .(carb), colwise(normalize))
#   carb        mpg cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec  vs  am gear
#1     1 0.29746835   0 0.19743178 0.62222222 0.74657534 0.29846154 0.00000000 NaN   1  1.0
#2     1 0.20886076   1 1.00000000 1.00000000 0.21917808 0.84923077 0.51552795 NaN   0  0.0
#3     1 0.00000000   1 0.82343499 0.88888889 0.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 NaN   0  0.0
#4     1 0.90506329   0 0.04066346 0.02222222 0.90410959 0.22461538 0.53416149 NaN   1  1.0
#5     1 1.00000000   0 0.00000000 0.00000000 1.00000000 0.00000000 0.80124224 NaN   1  1.0
```

Double check with a base function

```
ddply(mtcars, .(carb), colwise(max))
  carb  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear
1    1 33.9   6 258.0 110 4.22 3.460 20.22  1  1    4
2    2 30.4   8 400.0 175 4.93 3.845 22.90  1  1    5
3    3 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 18.00  0  0    3
4    4 21.0   8 472.0 264 4.22 5.424 18.90  1  1    5
5    6 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5
```

So in both cases, `ddply` orders the resulting data.frame in a way that the grouping variable is the first column and all others shifted to the right. You can also check what happens when you group by `.(carb, cyl)`.

One thing I would recommend you is consider using `dplyr` which is a newer package to work on data.frames. The dplyr-equivalent to your code would be:

```
library(dplyr)
passing <- passing %>%
          group_by(season) %>%
          mutate_each(funs(normalize), -c(1:4))
```

Where columns 1:4 are the columns you don't want to normalize.

By running

```
mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% mutate_each(funs(normalize))
```

you can see that `dplyr` doesn't reorder the columns.

On a side note:

To create your `season` variable, you could just use

```
season <- 2004:2013
```

or

```
season <- first_season:last_season
```

And, when I ran your code, most columns were of class `factor`s. You use

```
passing[, 4:28] <- apply(passing[,4:28], 2, as.numeric)
```

to convert them to numeric, but in case the data you have before that conversion consists of factors, like what I saw, you should use `as.numeric(as.character(...))` to convert correctly.

Hope that helps.